# delete all chars when '-' found php

Tags: php

Having strings like

```
$s1 = "Elegan-71";
$s2 = "DganSD-171";
$s2 = "SD-1";
```

what would be the best way to delete all chars from '-' to end like

```
$cleans1 = "Elegan";
$cleans2 = "DganSD";
$cleans2 = "SD";
```

There is `substr($s1, "-",4);`

```
substr(string $string, int $start, int[optional] $length=null);
```

but how to tell that it should remove all numbers and how to know numbers size as they are variable?

Comment: i believe you want preg_match and to use a regular expression. http://us2.php.net/preg_match

Comment: Maybe with [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
<?php
    $my_string = "happy-123";
    $hyphen_position = strrpos($my_string, '-');
    $fixed_string = substr($my_string, 0, $hyphen_position);
    echo $fixed_string;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list($cleans1) = explode("-",$s1,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$s1 = "Elegan-71";
if (strrpos($s1, '-')){
    $cleans1 = substr($s1, 0, strrpos($s1, '-'));
}else{
    $cleans1 = $s1;
}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are cleaning each string individually, and you don't want to end up with neither an array or a list, and that each string ends up in that pattern (dash and number), this should do the trick:

```
$cleans1 = preg_replace('/-\d+$/', '', $s1);
```

Answer (score 1):

[ststr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) can does it too.

```
$s1 = "Elegan-71";
$clean = strstr($s1, '-', true);
echo $clean;
```

Answer (score 1):

i like :

```
$cleans1 = strtok($s1, "-");
```

about [strtok](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)